# Disable return key in React Native TextInput

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native's TextInput. I noticed that `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` makes the keyboard's return key disabled until some text is entered. Is there a way to control the disabled state of the return key myself?

Answer (score 5):

Not at this time - This attribute maps directly into a UIKit attribute:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624432-enablesreturnkeyautomatically

I couldn't find any particular hooks in this API to manually manage the enabled/disabled state of the submit button either.